# PHP - Parse String with Regex

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I grab the URI string with php code. 
The URI could be:

```
solution 1 - http://www.site.com/one/two/
OR
solution 2 - http://www.site.com/one/two/var_abcdefg.html
OR
solution 3 - http://www.site.com/one/two/var_abcdefg.html?var=123456
OR
solution 4 - http://www.site.com/one/two/?var=123456
```

I would like to split the string in:

```
solution 1:
var 1 = "http://www.site.com/one/two/";
var 2 = "";
var 3 = "";
solution 2:
var 1 = "http://www.site.com/one/two/";
var 2 = "var_abcdefg.html";
var 3 = "";
solution 3:
var 1 = "http://www.site.com/one/two/";
var 2 = "var_abcdefg.html";
var 3 = "?var=123456";
solution 4:
var 1 = "http://www.site.com/one/two/";
var 2 = "";
var 3 = "?var=123456";
```

How I Can make it?

Comment: Try [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is faster way:

[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php)

```
$input  = 'http://www.site.com/one/two/var_abcdefg.html?var=123456';
$output = parse_url($input);

array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(12) "www.site.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(25) "/one/two/var_abcdefg.html"
  ["query"]=>
  string(10) "var=123456"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need of regex, PHP has a built-in function that breaks a url into parts : [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use RegEx instead of `parse_url()`, you could try this:

```
$url = 'http://www.site.com/one/two/var_abcdefg.html?var=123456';

preg_match('#^([^?]*?)([^/?]*)(\?.*|)$#', $url, $match);

$var_1 = $match[1]; // http://www.site.com/one/two/
$var_2 = $match[2]; // var_abcdefg.html
$var_3 = $match[3]; // ?var=123456
```